# How to Parse JSON Array with Gson

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, gson

I want to parse JSON arrays and using gson. Firstly, I can log JSON output, server is responsing to client clearly.

Here is my JSON output:

```json
 [
      {
           id : '1',
           title: 'sample title',
           ....
      },
      {
           id : '2',
           title: 'sample title',
           ....
     },
      ...
 ]
```

I tried this structure for parsing. A class, which depends on single `array` and `ArrayList` for all JSONArray.

```java
 public class PostEntity {

      private ArrayList<Post> postList = new ArrayList<Post>();

      public List<Post> getPostList() { 
           return postList; 
      }

      public void setPostList(List<Post> postList) { 
           this.postList = (ArrayList<Post>)postList; 
      } 
 }
```

Post class:

```java
 public class Post {

      private String id;
      private String title;

      /* getters & setters */
 }
```

When I try to use gson no error, no warning and no log:

```java
 GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
 Gson gson = gsonb.create();

 PostEntity postEnt;
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonOutput);
 postEnt = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.toString(), PostEntity.class);

 Log.d("postLog", postEnt.getPostList().get(0).getId());
```

What's wrong, how can I solve?

Answer (score 275, accepted):

You can parse the `JSONArray` directly, don't need to wrap your `Post` class with `PostEntity` one more time and don't need new `JSONObject().toString()` either:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonOutput = "Your JSON String";
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Post>>(){}.getType();
List<Post> posts = gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);
```

Comment: Hi how to parse nested json array data like this .... [
  {
    "firstName": "Bidhan",
    "lastName": "Chatterjee"
  },
  [
    {
      "type": "personal",
      "number": "09832209761"
    },
    {
      "type": "fax",
      "number": "91-342-2567692"
    }
  ]
]

Comment: Is there a benefit to using the TypeToken?  From my tests, gson seems to handle a List<Object> field without using TypeToken.

Comment: Is there any way to user generic class instead of "Post". how can i parse for the generic class.

Comment: It resolved my issue but there is no need of casting with `(List<Post>) here as IDE reports it to be redundant.

Comment: What if i have T instead of Post, it's converting returning List<LinkedHashMap> !!!!!!!!!!!! any  idea ?

Comment: I used your snippet but got the error JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for a way to parse object arrays in a more generic way; here is my contribution:

`CollectionDeserializer.java`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

public class CollectionDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Collection<?>> {

    @Override
    public Collection<?> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Type realType = ((ParameterizedType)typeOfT).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        return parseAsArrayList(json, realType);
    }

    /**
     * @param serializedData
     * @param type
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> ArrayList<T> parseAsArrayList(JsonElement json, T type) {
        ArrayList<T> newArray = new ArrayList<T>();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        JsonArray array= json.getAsJsonArray();
        Iterator<JsonElement> iterator = array.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            JsonElement json2 = (JsonElement)iterator.next();
            T object = (T) gson.fromJson(json2, (Class<?>)type);
            newArray.add(object);
        }

        return newArray;
    }

}
```

`JSONParsingTest.java`:

```
public class JSONParsingTest {

    List<World> worlds;

    @Test
    public void grantThatDeserializerWorksAndParseObjectArrays(){

        String worldAsString = "{\"worlds\": [" +
            "{\"name\":\"name1\",\"id\":1}," +
            "{\"name\":\"name2\",\"id\":2}," +
            "{\"name\":\"name3\",\"id\":3}" +
        "]}";

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Collection.class, new CollectionDeserializer());
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        Object decoded = gson.fromJson((String)worldAsString, JSONParsingTest.class);

        assertNotNull(decoded);
        assertTrue(JSONParsingTest.class.isInstance(decoded));

        JSONParsingTest decodedObject = (JSONParsingTest)decoded;
        assertEquals(3, decodedObject.worlds.size());
        assertEquals((Long)2L, decodedObject.worlds.get(1).getId());
    }
}
```

`World.java`:

```
public class World {
    private String name;
    private Long id;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Miere I do not understand how this converts from JsonArray to List<World>

Comment: Basically, it uses the CollectionDeserializer for every Collection found during the GSON deserialization process. CollectionDeserializer on its turn, infers through the Collection's generic parameter which class represents the object store on the collection it should deserialize. I hope this have answered your question. If you still have doubts, please, contact me at [miere00 at gmail.com].

Comment: Hi @Miere, this solution doesn't handle the original question. Your JSONParsingTest is an object with an array inside. How do you use your CollectionDeserializer to parse just an array, not an array wrapped in an object?

Answer (score 8):

To conver in Object Array

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
ElementType [] refVar=gson.fromJson(jsonString,ElementType[].class);
```

To convert as post type

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
Post [] refVar=gson.fromJson(jsonString,Post[].class);
```

To read it as List of objects TypeToken can be used

```
List<Post> posts=(List<Post>)gson.fromJson(jsonString, 
                     new TypeToken<List<Post>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: how about as ArrayList <Post> ?

Answer (score 3):

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Post>>() {}.getType();
List<Post> posts = new Gson().fromJson(jsonOutput.toString(), listType);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the answers of this post are valid, but using TypeToken, the Gson library generates a Tree objects whit unreal types for your application.

To get it I had to read the array and convert one by one the objects inside the array. Of course this method is not the fastest and I don't recommend to use it if you have the array is too big, but it worked for me.

It is necessary to include the Json library in the project. If you are developing on Android, it is included:

```
/**
 * Convert JSON string to a list of objects
 * @param sJson String sJson to be converted
 * @param tClass Class
 * @return List<T> list of objects generated or null if there was an error
 */
public static <T> List<T> convertFromJsonArray(String sJson, Class<T> tClass){

    try{
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<T> listObjects = new ArrayList<>();

        //read each object of array with Json library
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sJson);
        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

            //get the object
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            //get string of object from Json library to convert it to real object with Gson library
            listObjects.add(gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), tClass));
        }

        //return list with all generated objects
        return listObjects;

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //error: return null
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this in Kotlin using the following code:

```
val fileData = "your_json_string"
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val packagesArray = gson.fromJson(fileData , Array<YourClass>::class.java).toList()
```

Basically, you only need to provide an `Array` of `YourClass` objects.

Comment: Why are you using PrettyPrinting?

Comment: @antroid I forgot to remove it ^^

Answer (score 3):

```
[
      {
           id : '1',
           title: 'sample title',
           ....
      },
      {
           id : '2',
           title: 'sample title',
           ....
     },
      ...
 ]
```

Check Easy code for this output

```
 Gson gson=new GsonBuilder().create();
                List<Post> list= Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(yourResponse.toString,Post[].class));
```

Answer (score 1):

in **Kotlin** :

```
val jsonArrayString = "['A','B','C']"

val gson = Gson()

val listType: Type = object : TypeToken<List<String?>?>() {}.getType()

val stringList : List<String> = gson.fromJson(
                            jsonArrayString,
                            listType)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get List value without using **Type** object.

```
EvalClassName[] evalClassName;
ArrayList<EvalClassName> list;
evalClassName= new Gson().fromJson(JSONArrayValue.toString(),EvalClassName[].class);
list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(evalClassName));
```

I have tested it and it is working.