# How to convert JSONArray to List with Gson?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, arrays

In my Android project I'm trying to convert a received JSONArray to a List. With the help of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371274/how-to-parse-json-array-in-android-with-gson) I got a bit further. I now have the following code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JSONArray jsonArray = NetworkUtilities.getData("mymodeldata");
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MyModel>>(){}.getType();
List<MyModel> myModelList = gson.fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
```

Unfortunately it complaints at the last line that the method fromJson(String, Type) in the type Gson is not applicable for the arguments (JSONArray, Type). I don't really know how to solve this.

Does anybody know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you see the answer there, you can notice that the first parameter in the `fromJson()` method was a `String`(the json object). Try to use the `toString()` on the JsonArray like this:-

```
List<MyModel> myModelList = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), listType);
```

Comment: @kramer65: If it has helped you please accept the answer!

Comment: @R.J it gives me `could be refactored into a named _static_ inner class SIC_INNER_SHOULD_BE_STATIC_ANON
` how to fix it