# JSONArray to List with GSON

Tags: android, arrays, gson

I have an array like this:

```
[{"poolkost":"IWXI"},{"poolkost":"ILXI"},{"poolkost":"VGXI"}]
```

and want to put it in a List using the tutorial [How to convert JSONArray to List with Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133944/how-to-convert-jsonarray-to-list-with-gson)

My Code:

```
    String jsonStr = DBFunction.GetBoxer(GlobalClass.DIR);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType(); //ERROR 1
    List<String> PoolList = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, listType);  //ERROR 2
```

I get 2 errors:

Error 1:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.reflect.Type to android.renderscript.Type
```

Error 2:

```
The method fromJson(String, Class<T>) in the type Gson is not applicable for the arguments (String, Type)
```

I cannot fix the first Error, either the second...

Comment: the first one is a wrong import

Comment: android.renderscript.Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();?

Comment: java.lang.reflect.Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType(); seems to be right, and this fixed the second, too.

Comment: Just fix the import of `Type` and then you will be able to short it to `Type listType = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your imports.

Remove this:

```
import android.renderscript.Type;
```

Add this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
```

This should fix both problems.