# Realm - Do not update if property equals

Tags: android, realm

I am using realm for Android. I have the following code and it works but I was wondering if it is the best way to go about updating objects and if it would cause any performance issues.

Currently, I do not want to update an existing object if the status is set to processing.

```
List<WorkOrderObject> woList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < openWorkOrders.size(); i++) {
                if (!visnetawrap.isUserLoggedIn) {
                    return;
                }
                WorkOrderObject wo = visnetawrap.gsonClient.fromJson(openWorkOrders.get(i).toString(), WorkOrderObject.class);

                WorkOrderObject currWO = realmThread.where(WorkOrderObject.class).equalTo("id", wo.getOrderRawId()).findFirst();
                if (currWO != null) {
                    if (currWO.getOrderStatus().equals("Processing")) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                issueDateTime = AppUtils.formatTimestampToDateTime(wo.getOrderIssueDate());
                issueDateString = issueDateTime.toLocalDateTime().toString("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
                dueDateTime = AppUtils.formatTimestampToDateTime(wo.getOrderDueDate());
                dueDateString = dueDateTime.toLocalDateTime().toString("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);

                if (!issueDateString.equals("") && !issueDateString.equals("00/00/0000") && issueDateTime.getYear() >= now.getYear() && !dueDateString.equals("") && !dueDateString.equals("00/00/0000") && dueDateTime.getYear() >= now.getYear()) {
                    //Log.d("dueDate", dueDateString);
                    woList.add(wo);
                }
            }
            realmThread.beginTransaction();
            realmThread.copyToRealmOrUpdate(woList);
            realmThread.commitTransaction();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think basically it is the same.
Since you are worried about performance here are ways you can improve.

```
private static String PROCESSING = "Processing";
private static String DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
private static String EMPTY_DATE = "00/00/0000";

public void betterMethod() {
    List<WorkOrderObject> woList = new ArrayList<>(openWorkOrders.size());

    //I think this code doesnot need to be inside loop.
    if (!visnetawrap.isUserLoggedIn) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0, j = openWorkOrders.size(); i < j; i++) {
        //Since you are using gson there are ways to convert JsonArray to list directly which is a better way than this
        WorkOrderObject wo = visnetawrap.gsonClient.fromJson(openWorkOrders.get(i).toString(), WorkOrderObject.class);

        WorkOrderObject currWO = realmThread.where(WorkOrderObject.class).equalTo("id", wo.getOrderRawId()).findFirst();

        if (currWO != null && currWO.getOrderStatus().equals(PROCESSING)) { //Its cleanar way
            continue;
        }

        issueDateTime = AppUtils.formatTimestampToDateTime(wo.getOrderIssueDate());
        issueDateString = issueDateTime.toLocalDateTime().toString(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.US);
        dueDateTime = AppUtils.formatTimestampToDateTime(wo.getOrderDueDate());
        dueDateString = dueDateTime.toLocalDateTime().toString(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.US);

        //I assume you have stripped out code where it needs string
        //You can use TextUtils.isEmpty() or issueDateString.isEmpty() , 
        // issueDateString.equals("") does is creates new String which is empty and compares issueDateString with it while above methods just check the 
        //length of string
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(issueDateString) && !issueDateString.equals(EMPTY_DATE) && issueDateTime.getYear() >= now.getYear() && !TextUtils.isEmpty(dueDateString) && !dueDateString.equals(EMPTY_DATE) && dueDateTime.getYear() >= now.getYear()) {
            //Log.d("dueDate", dueDateString);
            woList.add(wo);
        }
    }
    if (!woList.isEmpty()) {
        realmThread.beginTransaction();
        realmThread.copyToRealmOrUpdate(woList);
        realmThread.commitTransaction();
    }
}
```

1. For loop can be very large so conditional statement like `currWO.getOrderStatus().equals("Processing")` will create an new string and compares. It's better to initialize the string before and pass as above.
2. [Converting JsonArray to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133944/how-to-convert-jsonarray-to-list-with-gson)
3. Why instantiating arrays like `new ArrayList<>(openWorkOrders.size())` and using for loop with list like `for (int i = 0, j = openWorkOrders.size(); i < j; i++) {}`
   [Streamlining Android Apps: Eliminating Code Overhead by Jake Wharton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6zKBZcg5fk)

Comment: openWorkOrders is a JsonArray and I loop through it because if I try to convert it to to a list sometimes phones will crash, so I think looping through the jsonarray and adding each object individually is better in that situation?

Comment: The user can log out at any time so if the for is looping it will cancel if the user logged out that is why if (!visnetawrap.isUserLoggedIn) {
                        return;
                    } is in the loop.

Comment: I think if this runs in main thread, i think user login and this will not happen at same time.

Comment: True, I have it running in AsyncTask.

Comment: Now we may get into little deep zone which i know very less relatively that what if userlogin occurs just after check for login ? You may want to make this loop i dont know like atomic or synchronized?