# How to properly parse JSON Array in Android

Tags: android, json, okhttp

Im trying to find an easy way to parse JSON data that are in an array. Ive been able to do this before with pure JSON Objects and OkHttp.

What I plan to do is make a simple recycler view that each row will contain the data from the JSON Array.

Note: there will be keys in each array that may or may not have a "viewers" parameter. If it does not exist I plan to make a default value of 0.

JSON example:

```
{
status_code: 200,
status_text: "OK",
errors: [ ],
data: {
items: [
{
stream: "channel1",
status: 1,
channel: 527,
provider: "akamai"
},
{
stream: "channel2",
status: 2,
channel: 565,
provider: "akamai",
viewers: 3
},
```

I have a class that stores the data (not sure if needed in the case of a JSON Array) called CurrentStreams.java

```
package com.example.concurrent;

public class CurrentStreams {
    private String mStream;
    private int mStatus;
    private int mChannel;
    private String mProvider;
    private int mViewers;


    public String getStream() {
        return mStream;
    }

    public void setStream(String stream) {
        mStream = stream;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return mStatus;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        mStatus = status;
    }

    public int getChannel() {
        return mChannel;
    }

    public void setChannel(int channel) {
        mChannel = channel;
    }

    public String getProvider() {
        return mProvider;
    }

    public void setProvider(String provider) {
        mProvider = provider;
    }

    public int getViewers() {
        return mViewers;
    }

    public void setViewers(int viewers) {
        mViewers = viewers;
    }


}
```

In my MainActivity I initiate a new OkHttpClient and create the request and pass a method called getCurrentDetails(jsonData) which contains the following

```
private CurrentStreams getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        //New JSON Array
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

            JSONObject items = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String streamName = items.getString("stream_name");
            int status = items.getInt("status");
            int channelId = items.getInt("channel_id");
            String cdn = items.getString("cdn");
            int viewers = items.getInt("viewers");
        }

    }
```

I assume im kinda lost at how to properly handle the JSON Array and save the data to then later populate the view with rows of data. Any help is greatly appreciated in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use gson.

You maybe want to take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8371455/6386583) or this [Tutorial](http://www.java2blog.com/2013/11/gson-example-read-and-write-json.html)