# how to extract jsonObject from jsonArray and set to string using setter method

Tags: android, arrays, parsing, arraylist

How to extract json inside participants and saving them inside arraylist.

participants:

```
[  
    {  
       "name":"David Hume",
       "email":"david@gmail.com"
    },
    {
       "name": "Confucius",
       "email": "confucius@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

Comment: I think that you have not done a lot of Research you can start learning beginning by these tutorial [Android JSON Parsing Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8371455/6723193). Possible duplicated question...