# JSON Conversion Exception to java object

Tags: android

I am facing json conversion exception. While i converting json to java object.

Here is my json

```
[  
   {  
      "PrefrenceId":"228f176d-d224-32d7-9bb5-6287a06a68e8",
      "UserId":"327e6c64-bc90-3ae8-8f7d-72837581ca13",
      "QuestionnaireId":"41f31b11-47f5-3e29-8c88-1a3615c978a7",
      "Suggestions":"",
      "Explanation":"",
      "IsActive":true,
      "IsDelete":false,
      "DateCreated":"2016-11-01 09:53:00.000",
      "DateUpdated":"2016-11-01 09:53:17.000"
   },
   {  
      "PrefrenceId":"52a74739-bdd3-33ac-a83f-72f60b1992b5",
      "UserId":"327e6c64-bc90-3ae8-8f7d-72837581ca13",
      "QuestionnaireId":"8cd5ac8e-89db-3d7b-bb2d-4e6735b245de",
      "Suggestions":"",
      "Explanation":"",
      "IsActive":true,
      "IsDelete":false,
      "DateCreated":"2016-11-01 09:48:53.000",
      "DateUpdated":"2016-11-01 09:53:15.000"
   },
   {  
      "PrefrenceId":"ae7fc877-b26a-34d3-a5f3-244c7e777e08",
      "UserId":"327e6c64-bc90-3ae8-8f7d-72837581ca13",
      "QuestionnaireId":"d3b98cde-111c-30d5-a4c9-412a76b656eb",
      "Suggestions":"Camping",
      "Explanation":"",
      "IsActive":true,
      "IsDelete":false,
      "DateCreated":"2016-11-01 09:53:02.000",
      "DateUpdated":"2016-11-01 09:53:19.000"
   },
   {  
      "PrefrenceId":"bcac0da7-31a6-345f-be82-ddff17c29b35",
      "UserId":"327e6c64-bc90-3ae8-8f7d-72837581ca13",
      "QuestionnaireId":"8fb1bda7-7ec8-3538-8aa8-ff84637764a4",
      "Suggestions":"",
      "Explanation":"",
      "IsActive":true,
      "IsDelete":false,
      "DateCreated":"2016-11-01 09:53:07.000",
      "DateUpdated":"2016-11-01 09:53:22.000"
   },
   {  
      "PrefrenceId":"ff46ce3c-70cb-3d25-8dbb-10e9c46d4c2d",
      "UserId":"327e6c64-bc90-3ae8-8f7d-72837581ca13",
      "QuestionnaireId":"3afffc17-30e4-311f-a0fc-8daa3bda6c98",
      "Suggestions":"",
      "Explanation":"",
      "IsActive":true,
      "IsDelete":false,
      "DateCreated":"2016-11-01 09:53:05.000",
      "DateUpdated":"2016-11-01 09:53:20.000"
   }
]
```

My POJO classes :-

```
public class SurvivorZAMQuestionList implements Serializable {
    public List<SurvivorZAMQuestionnaire> survivorZAMQuestionnaires;
}


public class SurvivorZAMQuestionnaire implements Serializable {
    public String Suggestions;

    public String PrefrenceId;

    public String IsActive;

    public String IsDelete;

    public String DateCreated;

    public String DateUpdated;

    public String UserId;

    public String QuestionnaireId;

    public String Explanation;
}
```

But when i am converting json response to json it is showing following error:-
**com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2**

Can anyone tell me what i am missing in pojo class.
Any kind of held should be appreciated.

Comment: from error, you need to change json response format or change your method for fetchig json response. Post your code for more detail solution

Comment: static <T> T getObject(String response, Class<T> clazz) {
        try {

            Object t = clazz.newInstance();
            Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            return (T) gson.fromJson(response, clazz);

        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }                   @Divyesh i amd using above code for converting response to json

Answer (score 2):

Your response is proper but your parsing is not proper. So first of all add GSON in your gradle file.

`compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'`

Now use below your code for parsing your response

```
try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray("put your response here");
        Gson gson =  new Gson();
        for (int i = 0 ; i <array.length();i++)
        {
            SurvivorZAMQuestionnaire obj = new SurvivorZAMQuestionnaire();
            obj.add(gson.fromJson(array.getJSONObject(i).toString(),SurvivorZAMQuestionnaire.class));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Add your obj in list and show it :)

Answer (score 1):

The Error clearly states that the Gson accepts `JsonObject` not `JsonArray`. In your case you can put the response `JsonArray` into a `JsonObject` with a key for that `JsonArray` and give that key as `annotation` in `SurvivorZAMQuestionList`. By this way you can easily sort this problem.

Hope this is Helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use GSON library -> `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'`

```
List<SurvivorZAMQuestionnaire> survivorZAMQuestionnaires;
...

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<SurvivorZAMQuestionnaire>>(){}.getType();
survivorZAMQuestionnaires = gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType);
```

`Type` is instance of `java.lang.reflect.Type;`

Answer (score 0):

Parse Your Json this way,

```
List<SurvivorZAMQuestionnaire> survivorZAMQuestionnaires = new      Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<SurvivorZAMQuestionnaire>>() {
    }.getType());
```

Comment: If you are parsing with "SurvivorZAMQuestionList" type then you need to add your complete json under a new JsonObject with key "survivorZAMQuestionnaires".

Answer (score 0):

Do a gradle dependency of gson.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```

Update code like this;

```
 private void parseJSON(String jsonMessage) throws JSONException {
            if (jsonMessage.startsWith("[")) {
                Type type = new TypeToken<List<SurvivorZAMQuestionnaire>>() 
                }.getType();
                List<SurvivorZAMQuestionnaire> survivorZAMQuestionnaireList =new Gson().fromJson
                        (jsonMessage, type);
                Log.d("Print List",survivorZAMQuestionnaireList.toString());
            }

        }
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

You need List of objects not only object, because your JSON contain list of objects. [How to Parse JSON Array in Android with Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8371455/3529309)