# Java: Convert string representation of array of arrays to an List of Objects

Tags: java, android

I have this String:

```
[["username1","name1"],["username2","name2"],["username3","name3"], ...]
```

And I want to get a List of User objects.

What is a good way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you put it in this format?  Wouldn't it be be easier just to have a JSON array of JSON objects, each of which is a user?

Comment: Where do you get a string like that? It would be easier to parse the contents if they were in some standard format (JSON/CSV etc). If you actually have the data in a 2D array, please let us know.

Comment: Actually this looks like a 2D array in JSON..

Comment: @GabeSechan this is a value of "users" key of a JSON response from server... i know this is a weird format and not that usable, but im not the one working on the server.

Comment: If it's JSON, there are many libraries out there that parse this for you effortlessly.

Comment: @DaniilOrekhov Then I'd push back on the server people to give me a better format.  You'll eat up a lot more in maintenance cost long term by not using proper design then you'll take to get it right now.  If necessary offer to make the change yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**User:**

```
Class User {
    String username, name;

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Convert JSON of 2D array to List:**

```
String json = [["username1","name1"],["username2","name2"],["username3","name3"], ...]
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
int count = array.length();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    JSONArray innerArray = array.getJSONArray(i);
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(innerArray[0]);
    user.setName(innerArray[1]);
    userList.add(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of my brain being boiled, I finally found a simple solution:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(users);

List<UserEntity> userList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
     JSONArray jsonUser = array.getJSONArray(i);
     UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
     user.setUsername(jsonUser.getString(0));
     user.setName(jsonUser.getString(1));
     userList.add(user);
}

return userList;
```

`users` here is the initial string, and `len` is the length of the `array`.

Comment: Great..You did it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a proper format to parse, i don't think it can be parsed with any proper way. The best thing I can suggest you is to break the String again and again with split function at "Bracket([)" and at "Inverted Comas ("")" by creating a logic to get all values one by one!

Comment: fortunately, it did work!! see my answer above if u r interested

Comment: That's interesting!