# How to parse this format of JSON using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am having Json in this format

```
{
    "Sheet1":
        [
            {
                "Title":"facebook",
                "Link":"facebook.com"
            },{
                "Title":"gmail",
                "Link":"mail.google.com"
            }
        ]
}
```

When I try to convert it using pojo I am getting two classes and I am not able to implement there is force close error
Please Help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Parse JSON Array with Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371274/how-to-parse-json-array-with-gson)

Answer (score 0):

Sheet1 is an array.

```
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) object.get("Sheet1");

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    String title = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Title");
    String link = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Link");
}
```

Comment: I am using Gson and volley library.

Comment: you asked how to parse the json... thats how you parse the json.

Answer (score 0):

This class structure will work for Gson:

```
public class Response {

    private List<Sheet> Sheet1;
}

public class Sheet {

    private String Title;
    private String Link;
}
```

Your top-level response has one element, `"Sheet1"`, which is a list of items. Each item in the list has two elements, `"Title"` and `"Link"`.

Comment: What about getters and setters

Comment: Add them if you want

Answer (score 0):

Create the classes:

```
public class Sheet {
    String Title;
    String Link;
}
```

and

```
public class Sheets {
    Collection<Sheet> Sheet1;
}
```

and after deserialize with:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String filename="pathTo/sheet.json";
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filename));
        Sheets sheet1= gson.fromJson(reader, Sheets.class);
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(sheet1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This class structure will work for Gson:

```
public class Response 
{ 
  private List<Sheet> Sheet1; 
} 
public class Sheet 
{ 
  private String Title; 
  private String Link; 
}
```

Your top-level response has one element, "Sheet1", which is a list of items. Each item in the list has two elements, "Title" and "Link".