# Android fetch volley data from a string of arrays

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

AM sending a request using android volley and get a response like this

```
   public void onResponse(JSONObject response

       try {
           String responsedata = response.getString("data");

              Log.i("test",responsedata);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

     }
```

The above log prints

```
[{"id":1,"identifier":"TYam Plant","header_val":"tyamplant"},
 {"id":2,"identifier":"Touron Plant","header_val":"toroun"}
]
```

Now i would like to loop through these and extract an array of individual properties that is

```
id, identifier, header_val
```

How do i go about this. Am still new to java

Comment: Since the response is Json you have two main options. 1. Deserialise it into a object. 2.Parse the json by hand a library. The Gson library by google supports both ways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You response is **`JSONArray`** not **`JSONObject`** check it

You need to use **`JSONArray`** request instead of **`JSONObject`** request of `volley`

Try this to parse your json

```
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(responsedata);
        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject object=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String id=object.getString("id");
            String identifier=object.getString("identifier");
            String header_val=object.getString("header_val");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Better to Parse your `JSON` Using [**`google-gson-library`**](https://github.com/google/gson)

> `Gson` is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their `JSON` representation. It can also be used to convert a `JSON` string to an equivalent Java object. `Gson` can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of

EXAMPLE : [**How to Parse `JSON` Array with `Gson`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371274/how-to-parse-json-array-with-gson)

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI happy to help you my friend

Answer (score 0):

1. You create a Custom Object with 3 field: id, identifier,header_val

```js
public class YourObject {
        private String id;
        private String identifier;
        private String header_val;

        public YourObject(String id, String identifier, String header_val) {
            this.id = id;
            this.identifier = identifier;
            this.header_val = header_val;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getIdentifier() {
            return identifier;
        }

        public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
            this.identifier = identifier;
        }

        public String getHeader_val() {
            return header_val;
        }

        public void setHeader_val(String header_val) {
            this.header_val = header_val;
        }
    }
```

2. Loop and add into list: `List<YourObject> yourList = new ArrayList<>();`

```js
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(responseString);
        for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject object=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String id=object.getString("id");
            String identifier=object.getString("identifier");
            String header_val=object.getString("header_val");
            yourList.add(new YourObject(id, identifier, header_val);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```